# Intrusive weak pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

`WeakPtr` can point to any object provided it inherits from `WeakBase`. So, for example, you could use it to observe an object managed by a `unique_ptr` (that's my use case). It is not possible to make this thread safe.

Curious what could be improved.

```
#ifndef WeakPtr_h
#define WeakPtr_h

#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

class WeakBase;

struct Remnant {
  bool alive = true;
};

// An intrusive zeroing weak pointer.
// Not thread safe.
template<class T>
class WeakPtr {

  std::shared_ptr<Remnant> _r;
  T* _p;

 public:
  WeakPtr(T* ptr = nullptr) : _r(ptr ? ptr->GetRemnant() : nullptr ), _p(ptr) { }

  WeakPtr(const WeakPtr& other) : _r(other._r), _p(other._p) { }

  ~WeakPtr() { }

  WeakPtr& operator=(const WeakPtr& other) {
    if(this != &other) {
      _r = other._r;
      _p = other._p;
    }
    return *this;
  }

  T* operator->() const { 
    assert(_r);
    assert(_r->alive);
    return _p;
  }

  operator bool() const { 
    if(_r) {
      return _r->alive; 
    }
    return false;
  }

  T* Get() const {
    if(_r && _r->alive)
      return _p;
    return nullptr;
  }

  std::shared_ptr<Remnant> GetRemnant() const {
    return _r;
  }

  T& operator*() const {
    assert(_r);
    assert(_r->alive);
    return *Get();
  }

  template<class T2>
  bool operator==(const WeakPtr<T2>& other) const {
    return _r == other.GetRemnant();
  }

  template<class T2>
  bool operator!=(const WeakPtr<T2>& other) const {
    return _r != other.GetRemnant();
  }

  template<class T2>
  bool operator<(const WeakPtr<T2>& other) const {
    // Compare remnants to ensure the order
    // is stable even after objects are deleted.
    return _r < other.GetRemnant();
  }

  void Print(std::ostream& out) const {
    out << _p;
  }

}; // class WeakPtr

class WeakBase {

  std::shared_ptr<Remnant> _r;

public:

  WeakBase() { }

  const std::shared_ptr<Remnant>& GetRemnant() {

    if(! _r)
      _r = std::make_shared<Remnant>();
    return _r;
  }

  virtual ~WeakBase() {
    if(_r)
      _r->alive = false;
  }

};

template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const WeakPtr<T>& p) {
  p.Print(out);
  return out;
}

#endif // WeakPtr_hpp
```

**Commentary**

It would be possible to eliminate `Remnant` and reduce the size of `WeakPtr` by using the `null_deleter` technique here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/smart_ptr/sp_techniques.html#weak_without_shared. However that results in needless atomic modification of the `shared_ptr` use count (via `weak_ptr::lock`) every time the pointer is used.

**Basic Usage Example**

```
struct TestWeakPtr : public WeakBase {

  virtual ~TestWeakPtr() { }

};

static void basicTest() {
  auto p = new TestWeakPtr;

  WeakPtr<TestWeakPtr> wp(p);

  assert(wp);

  delete p;

  assert(! wp);
}
```

Comment: But your using `std::shared_ptr` on the hood. Why add another layer on top of that. The point of having this type of class would be to reduce overhead of one of the standard standard smart pointers (but you don't achieve this).

Comment: Some more tips on smart pointer can be found here: http://lokiastari.com/blog/2014/12/30/c-plus-plus-by-example-smart-pointer/

Comment: @LokiAstari No, the point is to have a smart pointer which can observe an object managed by a `unique_ptr`, not to reduce overhead.

Comment: Please provide a usage example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve